# Replace dates in an array of date with values in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date

I have used the below link to create an array of date.

http://boonedocks.net/mike/archives/137-Creating-a-Date-Range-Array-with-PHP.html

However, I wanted to replace dates in that array by comparing the date(in the array) and the date(in query result).

If they are equal then I will replace that date in the array with the result in the mysql query.

array:

```
array(
      9/1/2013,
      9/2/2013,
      9/3/2013,
      9/4/2013,
      9/5/2013
 )
```

query result:

```
|   date    |  value0  |   value1  |   value2   |  and so on...
|  9/2/2013 |    5     |     A     |     AQ     |
|  9/3/2013 |    6     |     V     |     CD     |
|  9/5/2013 |    7     |     X     |     SA     |
```

the result must be like this:

```
PHP date    ---->     9/1/2013      0      
Database    ---->     9/2/2013      5
Database    ---->     9/3/2013      6
PHP date    ---->     9/4/2013      0
Database    ---->     9/5/2013      7
```

How do i do that in PHP? I've been experimenting with while loops inside foreach, but does not work.

What if i have several columns in my table? I've tried the answers below but i think it is just two dimensional? see above edit in my mysql query.

Edit:

I have done this now:

```
 <?php

    $getDays = array(
      9/1/2013,
      9/2/2013,
      9/3/2013,
      9/4/2013,
      9/5/2013
    );


$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getTime))
{
     $result[] = $row;
}

for($i=0; $i < count($getDays); $i++)
{

?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $result[$i]['date']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result[$i]['value0']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result[$i]['value1']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result[$i]['value2']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php

}
?>
```

But the problem is: some dates are not being outputted just like i wanted it to be in order.

Comment: what you have tried ? How the query result now ?

Comment: please submit the code you tried

Comment: something like foreach($getDays as $day){ $row = mysql_fetch_array($getTime); if($day == $row['date']){ //print $row[] values } else { //$day value } }

Answer (score 1):

The simpler option should be to make the date as key of the resulting array.

You may the process both array one at a time like this:

```
$outputArray = array();

//assuming $inputArray is your date array
foreach ($inputArray as $date) {
    $outputArray[$date] = 0;
}

//assuming $res holds the output of mysql_query()
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $outputArray[$row['date']] = $outputArray[$row['value']];
}
```

Comment: If am correct this time, you also want to know which date is from array and which one is from database. right?

In this case, multidimensional array will help for sure. But to have a simpler way forward, you may want to assign some unique value, instead of 0 here:
 $outputArray[$date] = 0;

But if you feel database can have any number, In PHP you may also assign a string. eg:
 $outputArray[$date] = 'INP';

So, now in the output array if value of a date is 'INP', its from array else from db.

Let me know if you want to go with multidimensional array way. I can write code for that.

Comment: yes, actually there are other fields in the table that i need to output.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the all the dates are store in a array named `$list`, the query result named `$query_result`, use a foreach to iterate all the date, use `isset()` to judge if the date is in `$query_result`:

```
<?php
$list = array(
    '9/1/2013',
    '9/2/2013',
    '9/3/2013',
    '9/4/2013',
    '9/5/2013',
);

$query_result = array(
    '9/2/2013' => 5,
    '9/3/2013' => 6,
    '9/5/2013' => 7,
);

foreach ($list as $date)
{
    if (isset($query_result[$date]))
    {
        echo "Database    ---->     $date      " . $query_result[$date] . "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "PHP date    ---->     $date      0" . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: need to put also the query result in an array?

Comment: @rmm04, yes, and use the date as key.

Comment: @rmm04, any question, please feel free to comment here.

Comment: i am actually having trouble in displaying other fields in my database, right for now i'm doing something like this  <?php echo $all_results[$i]['fields']; ?> to display the fields. i used for loop to iterate over my fields, but it does not return all results.

Comment: Sorry, I was busy all day. Can you add `var_dump($result)`, the paste the output in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give this a try... If it's way off, let me know and I'll help you get it figured out. :)

```
<?php
 $phpdates = array(
               '9/1/2013',
               '9/2/2013',
               '9/3/2013',
               '9/4/2013',
               '9/5/2013'
            );

 while ($allsqlresults = mysql_fetch_array($yourOriginalQueryHere)) {
    $mysqldates[] = $allsqlresults['date'];
    $mysqlvalues[] = $allsqlresults['values'];
 }
 foreach ($phpdates as $key => $phpdate) {
   if (in_array($phpdate, $mysqldates) {
     $text = 'PHP date';
     $column3 = $mysqlvalues[$key];
   }
   else {
     $text = 'Database';
     $column3 = 0;
   }
   print $text . $phpdate . $column3;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider with the following example:

```
 // PHP Date Array
 $array1 = array('9/5/2013', '9/6/2013', '9/7/2013', '9/8/2013');

 // Database Array
 $array2 = array('9/5/2013'=>'5', '9/8/2013'=>'7');

 foreach( $array1 as $arr ){
   if( array_key_exists ($arr, $array2) !== false ){
      echo "Database date    ---->    " . $arr . "    " . $array2[$arr] . "\r\n";
   }
   else {
      echo "PHP date         ---->    " . $arr . "    0\r\n";
   }
 }



// OUTPUT
Database date    ---->    9/5/2013    5
PHP date         ---->    9/6/2013    0
PHP date         ---->    9/7/2013    0
Database date    ---->    9/8/2013    7
```

and here is the live demo [on Codepad.org](http://codepad.org/fIYByf7h)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    '9/1/2013',
    '9/2/2013',
    '9/3/2013',
    '9/4/2013',
    '9/5/2013'
);

$query_array = array(
    '9/2/2013' => 5,
    '9/3/2013' => 6,
    '9/5/2013' => 7
);

$final_array = array();
foreach ($array as $date)
{
    if(isset($query_array[$date])) {
        $final_array[$date]["type"] = "Database date";
        $final_array[$date]["value"] = $query_array[$date];
    } else {
        $final_array[$date]["type"] = "PHP date";
        $final_array[$date]["value"] = 0;
    }
}

foreach($final_array as $date=>$each) {
    echo $each["type"]."    ---->   ".$date."     ".$each["value"]."<br>";
}

?>
```